# simplify a simple inequity with Sympy

Tags: python, math, sympy, inequalities

Let's say that I know that x is bigger than y and both x and y are bigger than 0.

Can someone please help me write a function that takes two linear formulas (+/- only) and returns which one is bigger?

For example:

```
foo("x+y","2*x") #should return 2
foo("2*x","x+y") #should return 1
foo("x","2*y") #should return 0 (can't decide)
```

thanks alot!

Comment: should the arguments be strings like `foo('x1+x2','2*x1')`?

Comment: @zhangxaochen : same meaning in Python.

Comment: @hivert np before the OP editing ;)

Comment: i fixed it anyway :-)

Comment: This is rather abstract, does `x1` mean `x^1`? Also, who can `x1 + x2` be less than `2x1`?

Comment: you're right about the second question. i changed it. x1 and x2 are parameters that the only thing you know is that x1>x2.

Comment: i changed x1 to x and x2 to y in order to make it more clear

Comment: What are your constraints on this? If you allow arbitrary expressions this can become quite complicated. Either way, first step is to parse the input and build a syntax tree/operation tree: (1) Tokenize (eg. by using RegEx), (2) build syntax tree by iterating over tokens and finally (3) Analyze syntax tree to get your answer (definitely not simple)

Comment: no arbitrary expressions at all! :-) only 2 parameters that can hold single integer and +/- operations.

Comment: When you say bigger do you mean by absolute value or more positive?

Comment: bigger = more positive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this in SymPy is to use the assumptions system.

First off, don't try to do tokenizing. Just use `sympify` if you have to input as strings, and if you don't have to, just create the expressions using symbols, like

```
x, y = symbols('x y')
a = x - y
b = 2*x
```

Please read the [SymPy tutorial](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html) for more information.

The assumptions system doesn't support inequalities directly yet, so to represent `x > y`, you need to state that `x - y` is positive. To ask if `2*x > x - y`, i.e., if `2*x - (x - y)` is positive, given that `x`, `y`, and `x - y` are positive, do

```
In [27]: ask(Q.positive((2*x) - (x - y)), Q.positive(x) & Q.positive(y) & Q.positive(x - y))
Out[27]: True
```

The first argument to `ask` is what you are asking and the second argument is what you are assuming. `&` is logical and, so `Q.positive(x) & Q.positive(y) & Q.positive(x - y)` means to assume all three of those things.

It will return False if it knows it is false, and None if it can't determine. Note that SymPy works in a complex domain, so not positive doesn't necessarily mean negative. Hence, you should probably call ask on the negated expression as well if you get None, or call it again with `negative` instead of `positive`.  If you want to include 0 (i.e., use `>=` instead of `>`, use nonnegative instead of positive and nonpositive instead of negative.

It isn't as smart as it could be yet, so you'll get a lot of Nones now when the answer could be known. In particular, I don't think it will really use the `x > y` fact very well at this point.